# include one maven project into another maven project using the relative path

Tags: java, maven, dependency-injection, dependencies, maven-plugin

I have 3 maven applications.

- library-module: common code that can be reused
- book-application: a web application that consumes the classes from `library-module`
- blog-application: a web application that consumes the classes from `library-module` too.

below are the poms of the modules:-

```xml
....
<!--library-application pom -->
<groupId>com.piyush</groupId>
<artifactId>library-module</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
....
```

```xml
....
<!--book-application pom-->
<groupId>com.piyush</groupId>
<artifactId>book-application</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
....
```

```xml
....
<!--blog-application pom-->
<groupId>com.piyush</groupId>
<artifactId>blog-application</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
....
```

Now I want to add `library-application` as dependency to `book-application` and `blog-application` as dependency like below:-

```xml
....
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.piyush</groupId>
    <artifactId>library-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
....
```

now the catch over here is that I want the `library-application` jar to be generated before or during the compilation of `book-application` or `blog-application`. So that I don't have to add the jar as provided dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build all three artifacts in one build, you can construct a multi-module project with three modules.

Comment: Thanks for your response, however, I am afraid that the multi-module approach does not suit my requirement. the 2 modules are independent of each other and they have a different lifecycle. the only common thing between them is the common library.

Comment: Then you either need to construct something in Jenkins (some build triggering), or you need to build the artifacts manually one after another. There is not Maven support for that.